# Interthread communication, switching between threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm in the process of learning how an operating system work, starting with Linux on Raspberry Pi. Currently, I'm writing a program that uses pthread to create multiple threads and communicate with each other. In this program, there will be 2 threads (3 if you count main()), 1 is writing and the other is reading, both threads uses a common struct to read and write and mutexes to signal each other (by checking for locks, lock and unlocking).

To check for thread communication, here's what I do:
The writing thread will read from a file called randStrings.txt, count number of 'e' and total characters of each lines then put those 2 numbers in a common struct.

The reading thread will write to a file called resultStrings.txt, reading from the common struct then write the number of 'e' (if e count is != 0) or otherwise, write '-' for the total length of that line.

So far, my thread can talk to each other, however, I can not do pthread_join() to go back and forth between 2 threads.

Here's my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*   
The following structure contains the necessary information  
to allow the function "dotprod" to access its input data and 
place its output into the structure.  
*/

typedef struct 
{
    int      e;     //number of e
    int      c;     //number of character
} DOTDATA;

/* Define globally accessible variables and a mutex */

#define NUMTHRDS 1
DOTDATA dotstr; 
pthread_t callThd[NUMTHRDS];

//Initialize mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutex_write = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_read = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_critical = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *writeMutex(void *arg)
{

    int     count;
    int     e_count;
    int     term_sig;
    FILE    *readf;
    char    my_lines[100];
    char    ch;
    signed int   numbers[2];
    int     i;
    char    s[50];
    term_sig = -1;

    //unlock write region
    printf("Write thread: Unlocking write mutex\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_write);

    //unlock critical region
    printf("Write thread: Unlocking critical mutex\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_critical);

    readf = fopen("randStrings.txt", "r");
    if (readf == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
    }
    //Read the file
    while ((fgets(my_lines, 33, readf))!=NULL)
    {
        e_count = 0;
        count = 0;

        my_lines[sizeof(my_lines) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", my_lines);
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(my_lines); i++){
            if(my_lines[i] == '\0') break;
            else if (my_lines[i]=='e'){
                e_count++;
            }
            else{ //if (my_lines[i] >= 'a' && my_lines[i] <= 'z'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        //lock write
        printf("Write thread: Locking write mutex\n");
        while(pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_write)!=0)
        {
            printf("Write thread: Locking write mutex\n");
        }

        //lock critical region
        printf("Write thread: Locking critical mutex\n");
        while(pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_critical)!=0)
        {
            printf("Write thread: Locking critical mutex\n");
        }

        printf("Write thread: Writing value\n");
        //write to global varibales
        dotstr.e = e_count;
        dotstr.c = count;

        //unlock critical region
        printf("Write thread: Unlocking critical mutex\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_critical);

        //unlock read
        printf("Write thread: Unlocking read mutex\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_read);
        printf("\nParent(%d) send value: [%d, %d]\n", getpid(), e_count, count);
        printf("Joining thread!\n");
        if((pthread_join(callThd[1], NULL)) !=0)
        {
            printf("Error joining with reading thread!\n");
        }

    }
    fclose(readf);

    //lock write
    printf("Write thread: Locking write, end signal, mutex\n");
    while(pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_write)!=0)
    {
        printf("Write thread: Locking write, end signal, mutex\n");
    }

    //lock critical region
    printf("Write thread: Locking critical, end signal, mutex\n");
    while(pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_critical)!=0)
    {
        printf("Write thread: Locking critical, end signal, mutex\n");
    }

    printf("Read thread: reading value\n");
    //write to global variables
    dotstr.e = term_sig;
    dotstr.c = term_sig;

    //unlock critical region
    printf("Write thread: Unlocking critical, end signal, mutex\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_critical);

    //unlock read
    printf("Write thread: Unlocking read, end signal, mutex\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_read);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *readMutex(void *arg)
{
    char    readBuffer[1000];
    FILE    *readf1;
    int     numbers_e;
    int     numbers_c;
    int     sig;
    int     j;
    sig--;
    //open the result file.
    readf1 = fopen("resultStrings.txt", "w");

    while(numbers_e != sig && numbers_c != sig)
    {           
        //unlock read
        printf("Read thread: Unlocking read mutex\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_read);

        //lock read
        printf("Read thread: Locking read mutex\n");
        while(pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_read)!=0)
        {
            printf("Read thread: Locking read mutex\n");
        }

        //lock critical region
        printf("Read thread: Locking critical mutex\n");
        while(pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_critical)!=0)
        {
            printf("Read thread: Locking critical mutex\n");
        }

        printf("Read thread: Reading value\n");
        //read global varibales
        numbers_e = dotstr.e;
        numbers_c = dotstr.c;

        //unlock critical region
        printf("Read thread: Unlocking critical mutex\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_critical);

        //unlock read
        printf("Read thread: Unlocking write mutex\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_write);

        readBuffer[0] = 0;      //reset readBuffer

        //Un-bundling data
        printf("\nConsumer (%d) Bundle received: [%i, %i]\n", getpid(), numbers_e, numbers_c);
        //readBuffer[0] = 0;
        if(numbers_e!= 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < numbers_e; j++){
                readBuffer[j] = 'e';
            }
            readBuffer[j+1] = '\0';
            for (j = 0; j < sizeof(readBuffer); j++) {
                if (readBuffer[j] == 'e'){
                    fprintf(readf1, "%c", readBuffer[j]);
                    printf("%c", readBuffer[j]);
                }
            }
            fprintf(readf1, "\n");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if(numbers_c != 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < numbers_c; j++){
                readBuffer[j] = '-';
            }
            readBuffer[j+1] = '\0';
            for (j = 0; j < sizeof(readBuffer) - 1; j++) {
                if (readBuffer[j] == '-'){
                    fprintf(readf1, "%c", readBuffer[j]);
                    printf("%c", readBuffer[j]);
                }
            }
            fprintf(readf1, "\n");
            printf("\n");
        }   
        if((pthread_join(callThd[0], NULL)) !=0)
        {
            printf("Error joining with writing thread!\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(readf1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Main program

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //other variables
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *status;   

    printf("Locking all mutexes...\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_read);
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_critical);
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_write);


    //Threads attribute
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    //pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    //Create threads
    printf("Creating writing thread...\n");
    pthread_create(&callThd[1], &attr, readMutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&callThd[0], &attr, writeMutex, NULL);


    printf("Creating reading thread...\n");
    for(;;){
    }

    printf("Program finished, deleting all mutexes...\n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_write);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_read);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_critical);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Output:

```
Locking all mutexes...
Creating writing thread...
Creating reading thread...
Write thread: Unlocking write mutex
Write thread: Unlocking critical mutex
kuuxfithomqjnyxqsdpagdue

Write thread: Locking write mutex
Write thread: Locking critical mutex
Write thread: Writing value
Write thread: Unlocking critical mutex
Write thread: Unlocking read mutex

Parent(2917) send value: [1, 24]
Read thread: Unlocking read mutex
Read thread: Locking read mutex
Read thread: Locking critical mutex
Read thread: Reading value
Read thread: Unlocking critical mutex
Read thread: Unlocking write mutex

Consumer (2917) Bundle received: [1, 24]
e

Joining thread!
Error joining with reading thread!
czfnvphqnmzhunukxhjvxbyncerxjba

Write thread: Locking write mutex
Write thread: Locking critical mutex
Write thread: Writing value
Write thread: Unlocking critical mutex
Write thread: Unlocking read mutex

Parent(2917) send value: [1, 31]
Joining thread!
Error joining with reading thread!
gzxwgojtnrnblyyshtqjrelwvif

Write thread: Locking write mutex
^C
```

EDIT 2:
Thanks to darron for pointing out my fault. By using pointers where I don't need it, they messed my results.

Now I found another problem, while jumping back and forth between 2 threads with pthread_join() , it can only jump once. The reading thread is done processing data from writing thread and writing thread still have more data to send but it can never call reading thread again to do that. Is there a way I can go back and forth between 2 threads? Maybe there's a simplier way to do this without pthread_join()?

Also, how do I stop the program after 2 threads finished their work? Right now, I have to put an infinite loop in main to keep them running without destroying all the mutexes before the threads finished but there's no way to stop them except CTRL + C.

Comment: Simplify your program at least twice. Close to -1.

Comment: You need to read the guidelines on posting questions here.

Comment: I really can't, all for loops in my program is to manipulate the char from the text files. For some reason, my Pi kept adding random characters at the end of the string, although I already put '\0' at the end of the string. I have to add more conditions to for loop to prevent it from adding non-alphabetical to the string but that does not eliminate the problem

Comment: Things like "while(pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_critical)!=0)` are absolutely terrible. The "If at first you don't succeed, fail fail again..." mantra has no place in pthread programming. From everything I see, this code needs *a* mutex (single), *a* condition variable (single), and *a* blob of predicate data the threads communicate with, including a flag to indicate shutdown state.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a lot of pointers ('*' characters) when you really don't need them. You don't seem to know what they're for...  If you're using something as a number simply use 'int', not 'int *'...